# Wildcard forward all posts and pages with few exceptions

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, urls, htaccess

I want to move my domain from example.com to example.dev and also set a wildcard forward. I use WordPress for blogging, now I want all posts and pages to be moved to the new address but I want some pages to remain accessible with my previous address. For example:

```
example.com/post -> example.dev/post
example.com/post2 -> example.dev/post2
[all posts be redirected]
example.com/page1 -> example.dev/page1
example.com/page2 -> example.dev/page2
[all pages be redirected]

Exceptions:
example.com/pageN -> example.com/pageN (remain Same URL)
example.dev/pageN -> example.com/pageN (redirected to previous domain)
example.com/PageX -> accessible from both domains
```

I want both URLs to be used on a same WordPress installation, but some URLs (posts and pages) should be previewed on one domain and some on another and some on both, as explained.

If there's a way to give posts and some pages URL of domain 2 and give the rest domain 1 it would be awesome. Like, instead of forwarding pages and posts, just rewriting their URL. For example, all posts now are on domain example.dev by default but also listed on example.com.

I don't know how to explain this exactly.

Here's my current `.htaccess` file:

```
# Prevent rewritten requests (to the WP front-controller) from being redirected
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# The TARGET_DOMAIN environment variable holds the desired target domain (if any)
#  - for the requested URL
# eg. "example.com" or "example.dev" or empty for no redirect / accessible from both.

# Set the "default" target domain
#  - Any URLs not listed below will redirect to this domain
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN:arhnotes.com]

# URLs that should be redirected to (or remain at) the other domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bio [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/computing [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/donate [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/encrypt [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/genderless-pronouns [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gnu-linux-controversy [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/legal [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/readings [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/now
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN:alirezahayati.com]

# URLs that should not be redirected - accessible from both domains
#  - Sets TARGET_DOMAIN to empty string (ie. no target domain)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|css|js|jpg|gif|webp)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN]

# Redirect to the desired TARGET_DOMAIN (if any)
#  - if not already at the TARGET_DOMAIN
RewriteCond %{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} !^([a-z0-9.-]+)@@\1$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
```

A huge thanks and shoutout to [Mr. White](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/8259/mrwhite) for the great answer and help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
# Prevent rewritten requests (to the WP front-controller) from being redirected
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirect everything from "example.com" to "example.dev"
# Except for certain URLs that should stay at .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pageA-to-stay-at-com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pageB-to-stay-at-com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pageC-to-stay-at-com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.dev%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Redirect certain URLs from "example.dev" to "example.com"
#  - That should stay at .com (not .dev)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pageA-to-stay-at-com [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pageB-to-stay-at-com [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pageC-to-stay-at-com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Note the `!` (negation) prefix on the *CondPatterns* in the first rule block. This makes the condition successful only when the URL does *not* match. However, in the second rule block (no `!` prefix), the requested URL must match one of the stated URLs in order to be redirected back to `.com`.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed everything is working OK. This is to avoid potential caching issues.

---

Another (better) approach, avoiding repetition of the URLs:

```
# Prevent rewritten requests (to the WP front-controller) from being redirected
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Set an environment variable STAY_AT_COM if the requested URL 
# is one of those that should stay at the .com domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/pageA-to-stay-at-com [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/pageB-to-stay-at-com [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/pageC-to-stay-at-com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=STAY_AT_COM:yes]

# Nothing to change below here except for the domain names...

# Redirect everything from "example.com" to "example.dev"
# Except for the URLs that should stay at .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:STAY_AT_COM} !yes
RewriteRule ^ https://example.dev%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Redirect URLs back from "example.dev" that should stay at .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:STAY_AT_COM} yes
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

I've changed the conditions in the first rule block to exact string matches (`=` prefix), rather than regex (that were missing the end-of-string anchor). This shouldn't make much difference with the URLs you are using, but it is easier to enter and avoids potential conflicts in the future.

---

**UPDATE:** I'd overlooked that some URLs need to be accessible from *both* domains and not redirected. The above would redirect to one or the other (two-state). You need triple-state... one or the other or both.

Try the following instead (at the top of the `.htaccess` file):

```
# Prevent rewritten requests (to the WP front-controller) from being redirected
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# The TARGET_DOMAIN environment variable holds the desired target domain (if any)
#  - for the requested URL
# eg. "example.com" or "example.dev" or empty for no redirect / accessible from both.

# Set the "default" target domain
#  - Any URLs not listed below will redirect to this domain
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN:example.dev]

# URLs that should be redirected to (or remain at) the other domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bio [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/computing [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/donate [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/encrypt [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/genderless-pronouns [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gnu-linux-controversy [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/legal [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/readings [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/now
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN:example.com]

# URLs that should not be redirected - accessible from both domains
#  - Sets TARGET_DOMAIN to empty string (ie. no target domain)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|css|js|jpg|gif|webp)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN]

# Redirect to the desired TARGET_DOMAIN (if any)
#  - if not already at the TARGET_DOMAIN
RewriteCond %{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} !^([a-z0-9.-]+)@@\1$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Additional explanation:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bio [OR]
> ```

I've gone back to using a regular expression (regex) match. This gives you greatest flexible at the expense of additional complexity (although you can mix the two). The above matches any URL that *starts with* `/bio`. So, it will also match `/bio/` and `/bioanything`. Use an end-of-string anchor (`$`) to match `/bio` only. eg. `^/bio$`.

Using a regex will be required to avoid redirecting any URL that *starts* `/wp-admin`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} .
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} !^([a-z0-9.-]+)@@\1$
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
> ```

The first *condition* ensures we only try to redirect when there is a target domain set. The second *condition* checks to see whether the currently requested domain (ie. the `Host` header) is different to the TARGET_DOMAIN. If both of these checks are successful then it redirects to the target domain on the same URL.

As before, make sure your browser cache is clear before testing and test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time but none of the solutions you provided work. There's no redirect. I should mention again that both domains are being used on same WordPress installation.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the updated `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I did not understand. Include what updated .htaccess file? Should I put my current htaccess file there?

Comment: Presumably you've added the directives above to your root `.htaccess` file, changing the necessary URLs and domain names ... please edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file so I can check it. Conflicts with existing directives is a common problem - order is important.

Comment: Done. I copied my .htaccess file including real URLs.

Comment: You've incorrectly used a `!` prefix on the conditions in the first rule block. These should not be present in the 2nd version of the code above. (Ah, you aren't actually, using `.com` and `.dev` so that naming convention is a bit misleading!)

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `=/url` instead - this will be preferable as it matches the exact URL (not a regex), so will be easier to get right and avoid conflicts.

Comment: Done. But still no redirect. Updated the question with current httaccess file.

Comment: You will also need to clear your browser cache if you've previously experimented with 301 (permanent) redirects, since these will have been persistently cached by the browser.

Comment: Ah, sorry, just seen a bug (now corrected)... the domain should be expressed as `^(www\.)?example\.com` - the `?` after `^(www\.)?`  was missing in my code above. That makes the www subdomain optional. It would have previously only worked if you requested the www subdomain.

Comment: OK now the redirect works but pages that were supposed to stay at example.com are now redirecting to example.dev. For example, example.com/page1 should stay at example.com/page1 but it goes to example.dev. Not even example.dev/page1.

Comment: Also, some pages even don't stay at example.dev/pageX. They get redirected to example.dev.

Comment: Ah, the written URL (to the WP front-controller - `index.php`) is being redirected. I've added a directive at the top to prevent this. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: OK now redirect works fine. All pages redirect properly. However, some pages were supposed to stay at example.com and if they were accesses from example.dev, they should redirect to example.com. For example, example.com/bio should remain in example.com/bio and if someone goes to example.dev/bio, it should be redirected to example.com/bio. Now, all pages redirect to example.dev no matter what.

Comment: Updated the question with the newest htaccess file.

Comment: Also, now, even the WordPress URLs such as example.com/login or example.com/wp-admin and stuff are redirected to same URL on example.dev. This shouldn't happen.

Comment: Are the domains in your question the actual domains being used? I don't see any redirects? Also, your URLs appear to have trailing slashes (and WordPress redirects to append the trailing slash). This trailing slash is missing from the directives in the `.htaccess` file in the question so the URLs won't match. `/login` and `/wp-admin` should be redirected unless they are included in the list of URLs not to redirect (these aren't on the list you posted)? "and some on both" - Ah, I've overlooked this! All URLs are currently one or the other, not both! I'll have another think about this...

Comment: I've updated/rewritten my answer.

Comment: Now everything works perfect except for example.com/login and example.com/admin and example.com/wp-admin and example.com/wp-login which are redirected to example.dev/URL. They should be accessible from both domains.

Comment: I would select your answer as the correct one. Thank you very much dear. For all your help and time. I'm not accepting this just to see if the problem for /login /wp-admin etc. can be fixed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add those additional URLs to the "noredirect" list. And I've added all _static resources_ (images, JS, CSS, etc.) to the list as well, as these must not be redirected. If this still doesn't work then please update your question with your current `.htaccess` file so we can take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the htaccess file (in the question too) but still /login /wp-admin etc. are redirected to example.dev instead being available on both domains.

Comment: Sorry, I missed an `OR` flag from the penultimate `RewriteCond` directive on that rule block! (I've updated my answer.)

Comment: You're amazing. Thanks a lot man. I really appreciate all your help and effort and time. Thanks. It's perfect.

Comment: I added a small thank you note in the question too. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hey man would you please write a note on [the question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64710489/wildcard-forward-with-exception-of-a-few-addresses) that you answered the question here so I can select that as answer too?

Comment: Hey. I have a slight problem. I can't update page or post or even submit a new one (page or post) using example.com (first domain). I can do it using my example.dev but not example.com. When I want to compose a post, it doesn't show me post categories and stuff and when I click on post and/or update (on pages and posts) it says update/posting failed: you're probably offline. I think it may be because server can't get WordPress files as they are being redirected probably.

Comment: I tried everything and no success yet.

Comment: I posted a new question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/377841/server-wordpress-redirects-files-that-are-not-supposed-to-using-htaccess

Comment: "I think it may be because server can't get WordPress files as they are being redirected probably." - Yes, probably, you would need to examine the HTTP requests being made in the browser to identify all the requests that are being made (some of which may be triggered by JavaScript). I don't off-hand know what these requests would be unfortunately, but it could possibly vary depending on plugins etc. Alternatively, you change your approach and instead of redirecting "everything" from `.com` to `.dev` you only redirect select URLs. I'll continue my response in your new question.