Regex and config for redirecting all URLs, except /wp-admin and /specificpage, to a specific page within the same domain, using the Redirection plugin
Something like this:
domain.com/anystringexcept/wp-adminand/specificpage -> domain.com/specificpage
domain.com/wp-admin (no redirection)
domain.com/specificpage (no redirection)
Could anyone help me? Thank you.

You would have to ask the Redirection team if this was possible.  I suspect the best possible way to go about doing this is by editing the .htaccess file though:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/377773/60844

The solution is extremely simple.
Just create a rule redirecting all URLs to /specificpage with the position set as 1 (remembering to activate regex for the rule):
^.*

And two "do nothing" rules, one for /wp-admin and another one for /specificpage, both with the position set as 0.
That's all.
